# Chrome user agent stylesheet h1

Tags: google-chrome

I have a `font-weight:bold` in the user agent stylesheet.
But I don't want that, is there are any solution to fix that?

Alex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `font-weight: normal` in an appropriate selector within your site's stylesheet.